# I knew him/know him/had know him already

Tags: prepositions

Could anyone clear my doubt. I am very confused when to use KNOW and KNEW.

Suppose if there is a conversation between two people. A is introducing his new friend C to B.

A: Let me introduce my friend. He is XXXX.
B: I know(or KNEW?) him already before you even knew(or know? or had known?) him.

Anyone please correct the sentence.

Comment: Most native speakers wouldn't get bogged down in the possibility of a past perfect, because they wouldn't even bother to use the verb twice. *I knew him [even] before you [did]*.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in tense. *Know* is in the present-tense, while *knew* is in the past-tense. So in both instances of your sentence, you should use *knew* because both `Person A` and `Person B` **knew** `XXXX` before the conversation.

> Let me introduce my friend. He is XXXX. B: I **knew** him already before you **knew** him.